# Comparing with adjacent values in Python

Tags: python, iteration

I want to compare the minimum value of each row with the nearby elements. For example, min of first row occurs at Pe[0,1]. I want to compare this value with Pe[0,0], Pe[0,2] and Pe[1,1] and find the minimum amongst these three. Similarly for other rows. How to code it?

```
import numpy as np
Pe=np.array([[0.97300493, 0.4630001 , 0.66754101],
       [0.09043881, 0.03976944, 0.64823791],
       [0.9530546 , 0.40305156, 0.20944696]])

Pe_min=Pe.argmin(axis=1)
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I obtained the indices of the minimum values of each row but don't really know how to implement and compare with the nearby elements.

Comment: Please clarify the exact output required from those data and also whether you specifically need to use numpy

Comment: @OlvinRoght I am trying to sort minimum values amongst nearby/adjacent elements. Numpy is not mandatory.

Comment: Can you show us the example output you want?

Comment: I want the code to find the minimum on first row i.e. 0.4630001. Then find the minimum amongst the adjacent elements of this value i.e. find min amongst 0.97300493, 0.66754101 and 0.03976944.

Comment: I understand the question, I don't understand how you want the output formatted. Do you want two values returned per row, the minimum of the row and the minimum of the 5 cells surrounding that? I.e. `[[0.4630001, 0.03976944], [0.03976944, 0.03976944], [0.20944696, 0.20944696]]`?

Comment: Exactly. For first row, min is 0.4630001. I want the code to return [0.4630001, 0.03976944]. The second minimum is now 0.03976944. Now I want the code to scan the surrounding elements and return the minimum which is 0.20944696. Thus, the next output should be [0.03976944, 0.20944696].

Comment: The minimum of the surrounding elements is not 0.20944696 for the second row, it's 0.09043881?

Comment: Oops sorry...you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a vectorized solution in 4 steps by assigning the minimums with shifted sub ranges on the previous and next rows/columns:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.97300493, 0.4630001 , 0.66754101],
             [0.09043881, 0.03976944, 0.64823791],
             [0.9530546 , 0.40305156, 0.20944696]])

r = a.copy()
r[:,:-1] = np.minimum(r[:,:-1],a[:,1:]) # min with next columns
r[:,1:]  = np.minimum(r[:,1:],a[:,:-1]) # min with previous columns
r[:-1,:] = np.minimum(r[:-1,:],a[1:,:]) # min with next rows
r[1:,:]  = np.minimum(r[1:,:],a[:-1,:]) # min with previous rows

print(r)
[[0.09043881 0.03976944 0.4630001 ]
 [0.03976944 0.03976944 0.03976944]
 [0.09043881 0.03976944 0.20944696]]
```

Comment: Thanks. If I have a 10x10 matrix, is there a straightforward way to do?

Comment: These 4 steps will work for a 2D matrix of any size

Comment: Very smart solution! 

Comment: @AlainT. Can you please explain the output format?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looping over your rows, but it's a bit tedious, I'm sure there's a smarter way:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.97300493, 0.4630001 , 0.66754101],
             [0.09043881, 0.03976944, 0.64823791],
             [0.9530546 , 0.40305156, 0.20944696]])
b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], 2))

for row_n, row in enumerate(a):
   # Get row min
   b[row_n][0] = np.min(row)
   
   # Get surroundings min
   i = np.argmin(row)
   near = []
   if row_n > 0:
      near.append(a[row_n-1][i])
   if row_n+1 < b.shape[0]:
      near.append(a[row_n+1][i])
   if i > 0:
      near.append(a[row_n][i-1])
   if i+1 < b.shape[1]:
      near.append(a[row_n][i+1])
   b[row_n][1] = min(near)

print(b)
# array([[0.4630001 , 0.03976944],
#       [0.03976944, 0.09043881],
#       [0.20944696, 0.40305156]])
```

Comment: Thanks. This should probably work for a n-dimensional square matrix as well with random numbers.

Comment: No problem! I have hardcoded it to only work in 2 dimensions I think, and it won't be very perfomant. I'm sure we could use [`nditer`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.nditer.html#arrays-nditer) to do it faster...

Comment: Is it possible to represent this using a heatmap to basically show a connected path between different minimum values?

Comment: I don't store the index of the minimum values in this particular implementation, but it would be easy to add another column or two to the ouput array that captures the row and column indices. I'll leave that to you though.